# Write, $q =-e^{-3m}\left({27m^4 +27m^3 + 18m^2+ 6m \over 81m}\right)$ in terms of f

Tags: exponential-function, inverse-function, lambert-w

if,
$$f(m) = -e^{-3m} \left({27m^3 + 18m^2 +6m \over 3m} \right)$$
and,
$$q(m) =-e^{-3m}\left({27m^4 +27m^3 + 18m^2+ 6m \over 81m}\right)$$
note that, here, $m \ge 0$.
How to write q as a function of f. That is in the form q(f(m)).
My try towards a solution is given below. I hope someone can help me. Thank you!

$$q(m) = -{27m^4 e^{-3m} \over 81m} - e^{-3m}\left( {27m^3+18m^2+6m \over 27 \times 3m} 
\right) $$
$$q = -{m^3 e^{-3m} \over 3} - {f(m) \over 27 }$$
I am stuck here. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Why isn't ${27m^3 + 18m^2 +6m \over 3m}$ reduced?

Comment: @RiverLi, Thank you for your response. it can be reduced but I thought ill keep it that way so that I can easily substitute it.

Comment: OK. Any information about the question?